# Insert a checkbox array once into a mysql query using php

Tags: php, mysql, cordova

I am trying to insert an array of objects, by one entry, into a mySQL database during a registration form by using checkboxes.

At the moment the entry is showing up as "array" only, and no entries from the array.

I tried a for loop but it inserted the whole entry into the database a number of times instead of just the checkbox entries.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <form id="callAjaxForm">
                                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                        <td width="150">Name:</td>
                                        <td width="300"><input type="text" name="inputName" value="" /> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="150">Username:</td>
                                    <td width="300"><input type="text" name="inputUsername" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="150">Password:</td>
                                    <td width="300"><input type="password" name="inputPassword" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="150">Date of Birth:</td>
                                    <td width="300"><input type="date" name="inputDOB" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="150">Core Competencies:</td>
                                    <td width="300">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="coreComp[]" value="1" />Honesty<br />
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="coreComp[]" value="2" />Loyalty<br />
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="coreComp[]" value="3" />Trust<br />
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="coreComp[]" value="4" />Empathy<br />
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="coreComp[]" value="5" />Respect</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <h3 id="notification"></h3>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </table>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
include 'includes/Connect.php';

$name = $_POST['inputName'];
$username = $_POST['inputUsername'];
$password = $_POST['inputPassword'];
$dob = $_POST['inputDOB'];
$aCC = $_POST['coreComp'];

$encrypt_password=md5($password);

if(empty($aCC))
{
    echo("Please pick at least one");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Profile (`Name`,`Username`,`Password`,`D.O.B`,`CC`) VALUES('$name','$username','$encrypt_password','$dob','$aCC')") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close();

    echo("You have successfully registered!");
}
?>
```

Comment: Your checkbox coreComp is an array so yes if you try to insert directly that it will not work. How u want to insert one entry for each selected item or all in one row ?

Comment: It is an array (at least when at least one of them is checked...). How do yo want to store it, all in the same column? If so, you'd need to serialize the array or someting similar but that makes searching a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use implode and explode.

```
$aCC = implode( ';' , $_POST['coreComp'] );
$aCC will contain all values glued together with a ';' in between them.
```

With this you can store it in the database. When you retrieve the data from the database make sure to use explode.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked a treat.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you set this as the answer if this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't store an array, you can concat with comma and insert it into the field using implode() function in php. [Check here](https://www.php.net/function.implode).

Another way is to keep the Core competencies in separate table with values and populate the same in checkboxes with unique id in value of checkbox, so you can store the ids in the field as a comma separated one.

Hope this helps.